# Loop'ing over arrays or lists indifferently

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

## Problem

Let's say you have a number of lists or arrays, let's say two for the sake of example :

```
(defparameter *arr* #(1 2 3))
(defparameter *list* '(4 5 6))
```

You can `loop` over them using either `across` or `in` keywords :

```
(loop for elem across *arr* do (format t "~a" elem))
     => 123
(loop for elem in *list* do (format t "~a" elem))
     => 456
```

I want to be able to `loop` over these arrays or lists using the same syntax. I am using SBCL and execution speed is a concern.

## Using `being the elements of`

This syntax is nice, as it works regardless of its argument being a `list` or `array`.

```
(loop for elem being the elements of *arr* do (format t "~a" elem))
     => 123
(loop for elem being the elements of *list* do (format t "~a" elem))
     => 456
```

But its speed is horrendous. If we do a quick comparison by accessing lists or arrays of 100 elements 1M times :

```
(format t "# Test 1.1.1 : Accessing list of doubles with loop 'in': ") (terpri)
(let ((test-list (make-list 100 :initial-element 12.2d0))
      (testvar 0d0))
  (declare (optimize (speed 3))
           (type list test-list)
           (type double-float testvar))
  (time (dotimes (it 1000000 t) (loop for el in test-list do
                                      (setf testvar (the double-float el))))))

(format t "# Test 1.1.2 : Accessing list of doubles with loop 'elements': ") (terpri)
(let ((test-list (make-list 100 :initial-element 12.2d0))
      (testvar 0d0))
  (declare (optimize (speed 3))
           (type list test-list)
           (type double-float testvar))
  (time (dotimes (it 1000000 t) (loop for el being the elements of test-list do
                                      (setf testvar (the double-float el))))))

(format t "# Test 1.2.1 : Accessing simple-array of doubles using loop 'across' : ") (terpri)
(let ((test-array (make-array 100 :initial-element 12.2d0 :element-type 'double-float))
      (testvar 0d0))
  (declare (optimize (speed 3))
           (type double-float testvar)
           (type simple-array test-array))
  (time (dotimes (it 1000000 t) (loop for el across test-array do
                                      (setf testvar (the double-float el))))))

(format t "# Test 1.2.2 : Accessing simple-array of doubles using loop 'elements' : ") (terpri)
(let ((test-array (make-array 100 :initial-element 12.2d0 :element-type 'double-float))
      (testvar 0d0))
  (declare (optimize (speed 3))
           (type double-float testvar)
           (type simple-array test-array))
  (time (dotimes (it 1000000 t) (loop for el being the elements of test-array do
                                      (setf testvar (the double-float el))))))
```

It gives us :

```
# Test 1.1.1 : Accessing list of doubles with loop 'in': 
Evaluation took:
  0.124 seconds of real time
  0.123487 seconds of total run time (0.123471 user, 0.000016 system)
  99.19% CPU
  445,008,960 processor cycles
  672 bytes consed
  
# Test 1.1.2 : Accessing list of doubles with loop 'elements': 
Evaluation took:
  0.843 seconds of real time
  0.841639 seconds of total run time (0.841639 user, 0.000000 system)
  99.88% CPU
  3,034,104,192 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
  
# Test 1.2.1 : Accessing simple-array of doubles using loop 'across' : 
Evaluation took:
  0.062 seconds of real time
  0.062384 seconds of total run time (0.062384 user, 0.000000 system)
  100.00% CPU
  224,896,032 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
  
# Test 1.2.2 : Accessing simple-array of doubles using loop 'elements' : 
Evaluation took:
  1.555 seconds of real time
  1.554472 seconds of total run time (1.541572 user, 0.012900 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.094 seconds GC time, and 1.461 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.94% CPU
  5,598,161,100 processor cycles
  1,600,032,848 bytes consed
```

I think it must use the `elt` accessor ? Anyway the penalty in speed is unacceptable.

## Trying to be smart with macros

I wrote something to be able to achieve my goal of having the same syntax for `list` and `array`. I think it's not great because it seems overly awkward, but here :

```
(defun forbuild (el-sym list-or-array list-or-array-sym)
  "Outputs either :
     * (for el-sym in list-or-array)
     * (for el-sym across list-or-array)
Depending on type of list-or-array.
el-sym : symbol, eg. 'it1
list-or-array : declared, actual data for list or array
list-or-array-sym : symbol name for the table, to avoid writing the data in full
                    in the 'loop' call using eval.
Example call : (forbuild 'it1 arr 'arr)"
  (cond ((typep list-or-array 'array)
         `(for ,el-sym across ,list-or-array-sym))
        ((typep list-or-array 'list)
         `(for ,el-sym in ,list-or-array-sym))))

(defun forbuild-l (l-elsyms l-lars l-larsyms)
  "forbuild but over lists of things."
  (let ((for-list nil)
        (list-temp nil))
    (loop for elem in l-elsyms
          for lar in l-lars
          for larsym in l-larsyms do
          (setf list-temp (forbuild elem lar larsym))
          (loop for word-temp in list-temp do
                (push word-temp for-list)))
    (nreverse for-list)))

(defun loop-expr (forlist body)
  "Creates the expression ready to be evaluated to execute the loop.
forlist : List of symbols to be inserted syntactically. eg.
          FOR IT1 ACROSS ARR1 FOR IT2 IN ARR2
body : all the expression after the 'for' clauses in the 'loop'."
  `(loop ,@forlist ,@body))

(defmacro looparl (element list-or-array &rest body)
  (let ((forlist (gensym)))
    `(let ((,forlist (forbuild2-l (quote ,element)
                                  (list ,@list-or-array)
                                  (quote ,list-or-array))))
       (loop-expr ,forlist (quote ,body)))))
```

Basically I build the right `loop` syntax from the arguments. The version of `looparl` given here can be called this way :

```
(let ((arr1 #(7 8 9))
      (list2 (list 10 11 12)))
    (looparl (it1 it2) (arr1 list2) do (format t "~a ~a" it1 it2) (terpri)))
=> (LOOP FOR IT1 ACROSS ARR1
  FOR IT2 IN LIST2
  DO (FORMAT T "~a ~a" IT1 IT2) (TERPRI))
```

The actual evaluation of this outputted expression is omitted in this example, because it doesn't work on non-global names. If we throw in an eval at the end of `looparl` :

```
(defmacro looparl (element list-or-array &rest body)
  (let ((forlist (gensym)))
    `(let ((,forlist (forbuild2-l (quote ,element)
                                  (list ,@list-or-array)
                                  (quote ,list-or-array))))
       (eval (loop-expr ,forlist (quote ,body))))))
```

And work on global variables, we see that we still have a speed issue, since there are evaluations happening at runtime :

```
(looparl (it1 it2) (*arr* *list*) for it from 100
              do (format t "~a ~a ~a" it1 it2 it) (terpri))
=> 1 4 100
   2 5 101
   3 6 102
(time (dotimes (iter 1000 t) (looparl (it1 it2) (*arr* *list*) for it from 100
              do (format t "~a ~a ~a" it1 it2 it) (terpri))))
=> Evaluation took:
  1.971 seconds of real time
  1.932610 seconds of total run time (1.892329 user, 0.040281 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.097 seconds GC time, and 1.836 seconds non-GC time. ]
  98.07% CPU
  1,000 forms interpreted
  16,000 lambdas converted
  7,096,353,696 processor cycles
  796,545,680 bytes consed
```

The macros are evaluated each one at a time a thousand times. But surely the type is known at compile time no ? The type of syntax in `looparl` is very nice, and I'd like to be able to use it without speed penalty.

I read this note in [Peter Seibel's book Practical Common Lisp, chapter "Loop for Black Belts"](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html)

> 3 You may wonder why LOOP can't figure out whether it's looping over a list or a vector without needing different prepositions. This is another consequence of LOOP being a macro: the value of the list or vector won't be known until runtime, but LOOP, as a macro, has to generate code at compile time. And LOOP's designers wanted it to generate extremely efficient code. To be able to generate efficient code for looping across, say, a vector, it needs to know at compile time that the value will be a vector at runtime--thus, the different prepositions are needed.

Am I committing some big Common-Lisp nonsense ? How would you go about creating a working, quick `looparl` ?

## Edit 1 : `FOR` library

Thank you Ehvince for the reference to the [`FOR` library](https://github.com/Shinmera/for). The `over` keyword in the `for:for` function is indeed exactly what I'd need. However the benchmarks are really underwhelming :

```
(let ((test-list (make-list 100 :initial-element 12.2d0))
      (testvar 0d0))
  (declare (optimize (speed 3))
           (type list test-list)
           (type double-float testvar))
  (time (dotimes (it 1000000 t) 
          (for:for ((el over test-list))
            (setf testvar (the double-float el))))))

(let ((test-array (make-array 100 :initial-element 12.2d0))
      (testvar 0d0))
  (declare (optimize (speed 3))
           (type simple-array test-array)
           (type double-float testvar))
  (time (dotimes (it 1000000 t) 
          (for:for ((el over test-array))
            (setf testvar (the double-float el))))))

Evaluation took:
  4.802 seconds of real time
  4.794485 seconds of total run time (4.792492 user, 0.001993 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.010 seconds GC time, and 4.785 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.83% CPU
  17,286,934,536 processor cycles
  112,017,328 bytes consed
  
Evaluation took:
  6.758 seconds of real time
  6.747879 seconds of total run time (6.747879 user, 0.000000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.004 seconds GC time, and 6.744 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.85% CPU
  24,329,311,848 processor cycles
  63,995,808 bytes consed
```

The speed of this library using the specialized keywords `in` and `across` is the same as for the standard `loop`. But very slow with `over`.

## Edit 2 : `map` and `etypecase`

Thank you sds and Rainer Joswig for the suggestions. It would indeed work for the simple case in which I would only have one array/list to iterate over. Let me tell you about one use case I had in mind : I was implementing a [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) wrapper, both as training and to have my own program in my toolkit. I wanted to take from the user lists or arrays indifferently to serve as series to pipe to gnuplot. This is why I need to be able to loop over multiple array/lists simultaneously + using the elegant loop clauses for iteration number etc.

In this use case (gnuplot wrapper), I only have two or three `for` clauses in my `loop` for each "data block", so I have thought of writing each combination depending on the type of input by hand and it is possible, but very awkward. And I'd be stuck if I had to do something like :

```
(loop for el1 in list1
      for el2 across arr1
      for el3 in list2
      for el4 in list3
      ...)
```

With the `list-i` and `arr-i` being inputs. Another fallback plan for this use case is just to convert everything to arrays.

I thought that since it is quite easily conceptualized, I could write something flexible and fast once and for all, but there must be a reason why it is neither in the specs nor in SBCL-specific code.

Comment: `being the elements of` is a non-standard (i.e., non-ANSI) extension to the loop macro. It is supported in SBCL, but I don't know what other implementations would be able to handle it.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called
[`map`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map.htm):
both

```
(map nil #'princ '(1 2 3))
```

and

```
(map nil #'princ #(1 2 3))
```

print `123`.

However, lists and arrays are very different beasts, and it is best to decide in advance which one you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

The library [For](https://github.com/Shinmera/for), by Shinmera, has the generic `over` iterator:

```
(ql:quickload "for")

(for:for ((a over *arr*)
          (b over *list*))
       (print (list a b)))

;; (1 4) 
;; (2 5) 
;; (3 6)
```

It also has "in" and "accross", so it might help to use "over" during development and to refine later, if needed.

I'll let you do the benchmarks :)

Answer (score 3):

For trivial uses you might do

```
(flet ((do-something (e)
         ...))
  (etypecase foo
    (vector (loop for e across foo do (do-something e)))
    (list   (loop for e in     foo do (do-something e))))
```

The runtime type dispatch probably will be faster than a generic iteration construct using the sequence abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

Coercing an array to a list and then looping in gives the same performance as if it had been a list in the first place, which isn't as good as with array, but not nearly so bad as using element and it does have the virtue of working with either a list or an array without additional machinery:

`(loop for x in (coerce array 'list) do something)`